# How to move ListBox items to another ListBox in django using jQuery and insert, update into database?

Tags: python, jquery, django

How to move ListBox items to another ListBox in **django** using jQuery and insert, update into database?[image]

Comment: to insert/update into database you have to send data to server/django and insert/update it in Python code - and this doesn't need jQuery.

Comment: for `jQuery` it is NOT `ListBox` but some `<select>` or other HTML tag. And if it has `ID` then you can use ID to access this element and move from one tag to another - but this needs to learn `JavaScript`